# Universal image loader recache from Internet

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I use the Android Universal image loader, 
and I set `cacheInMemory` and `cacheOnDisc` values to true.
Therefore, the imageloader downloads the images from the Internet, 
and there images will be cached in order to load much more fast at the next time.
My question is that if these URLs of images are same but its contents are changed, 
how the imageloader determine and resolve that situation and refresh these images of caches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default UIL doesn't check if image was changed on server. If image was cached on disk it will be used until it's deleted. So there are `LimitedAgeMemoryCache` and `LimitedAgeDiscCache` are exists for this case. They delete cached images after some time amount so updated images are loaded from server.